# I want to create a virtual machine for study mysql

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, server, virtualization, qemu

I am a learner DBA. I want to check Replication, Clustering etc on my Ubuntu. Which require more machines. So please instruct me how to create more VM on Ubuntu which are connected through LAN.

Ver Detail - Mysql 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log (Ubuntu)

Waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can install VirtualBox on your host system ([download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads))
2. And download an Ubuntu server iso ([download](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server))
3. Then, create virtual disk on VirtualBox and install system with downloaded server iso file.
4. Open your settings of virtual Ubuntu server, then set network as bridged to get all of them in your local network ([link](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged))
5. Go to $HOME/VirtualBox VMs directory and multiply several copies of your virtual server machine's directory with different names.

Now you have several virtual servers in same local network